# Unity vs MEF in the context of Prism app?

Tags: mvvm, architecture, unity-container, prism, mef

I'm looking to create my first app with PRISM, I downloaded it(the V5), I'm quite ready to got, but there is still something that bother me.

Unity or MEF.

Is there any thing that I cannot do if I choose the one vs the other?

I mean, I checked the two quickstart example provided with PRISM, and it seems to me this is only a matter of taste.

I searched over internet, and most pages tells that Unity cannot discover modules and so on, but (as far I understood), in the case of a Prism application, Prism does that for Unity.

So my final question:
 - Is choosing Unity or MEF only a question of "taste", or is there really something(limitation, functionality, ease of use) that should make me choose one or the other ?

Thank you very much

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prism v4: Unity or MEF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340263/prism-v4-unity-or-mef)

Answer (score 18):

**Unity** creates new instance of type by default.

**MEF** creates singleton instance of type by default.

**Unity** does not require registration for classes. This means you can instantiate any other third party type.

**MEF** requires Export attribute to be specified on the class. MEF cannot create instance of third party type unless it defines Export.

**Unity** requires type registration in code for interface types.

**MEF** No registration, simple Export attribute does it all.

**Unity** container can compose IUnityContainer property in the composed class where you can further access it easily in your own scope. This behavior is not useful for Plugin architecture as getting access to IUnityContainer may result in full access to your application.

**MEF** does not allow composition of CompositionContainer, which blocks access to MEF in your own scope if you do not have CompositionContainer. This is useful in Plugin architecture where third party code has limited access to your application.

**Unity** offers injection method mechanism, that can define IUnityContainer parameter and get the unity container object, with which you can compose other private properties manually.

**MEF** can only compose public properties, this is dangerous as anyone can change public property and make application crash easily.

Inside your application’s framework code, Unity serves the best as it gives you full control over type hierarchy, lifecycle and allows you to utilize third party components easily without writing much of code.

Inside your application, MEF will put lots of restrictions in which your framework can operate as it cannot easily compose third party components and it will force you to write numerous attributes in your code without which it will fail drastically.

Mostly, User Interface objects like your View, or UserControl or any UIElement can never be shared as no UIElement can have two parents at same time. So default behavior of Unity to create a new instance of type is very helpful.

Default behavior of MEF will create only one single instance of UI object, that will lead to trouble, not only that, if UI object is third party tool, MEF will not compose it. You can create multiple copies of exported type by specifying one more attribute called [PartCreationPolicy(Shared)], however it is very time comsuming and tedious to define this one every UI related type we create.

Unity does allow singleton objects, but for that you have to register an instance to the container.

**MEF** by default creates singleton object only.

**Unity** does not allow multiple registrations for same instance in same scope sharing same interface but different type.

**MEF** allows multiple singleton objects of different type sharing same interface.

**Unity** works best for MVVM, as composing user interface parts can be very easy with unity.

**MEF** does not work great with MVVM as it will create singleton objects that will behave strangely in runtime and lead to UI failure.

**Unity** is not good for Modularity, as composing IUnityContainer will offer more control of unity lifecycle to third party modules.

**MEF** is good for Modularity, as it will not allow modification of composition thus offering great deal of security between modules.

So, to develop a framework, MVVM Crud application and a UI framework, Unity is the best.

To expose some functionality of your application for third party modules to register and access limited functionality, MEF is the best.

Comment: I read that in the PRISM case, we mostly need a DI library, and that MEF isn't about DI, so I should anyway use Unity or any other DI lib, is that true? The more I read, the more I've the impression that Unity fits better, and where MEF is better, prism is here to reduce the gap(Module discovery)

Comment: You aren't going to give credit to the blog you took your answer from (verbatim)?

http://akashkava.com/blog/391/mef-vs-unity-in-composite-application-prism/